# My favourite hobby is + verb + ing

Tags: gerunds

Could you help me?

Are these sentences correct or should I  change them somehow? I'm particularly curiuos if I can say "My favourite hobby is playing football" or if I must write: "My favourite hobby is football." Can I use "verb+ing" after hobby? Is playing football all right or awkward?

> My favourite hobby is playing football.
>
> My favourite hobby is horse riding.
>
> My favourite hobby is swimming.
>
> My favourite hobby is painting.
>
> My favourite hobby is reading.
>
> My favourite hobby is dancing.
>
> My favourite hobby is listening to music.
>
> My favourite hobby is cooking.
>
> My favourite hobby is playing games.

Answer (score 2):

All your sentences are correct. Since sentences usually exist in a context, people will understand what you mean.

> My hobby is football.
>   My hobby is playing football.

But if there's no context it's not clear from the first sentence if you are a footballer or a fan.

Comment: I figured ***football*** might be an awkward hobby to easily identify the "participant / fan" distinction, so I searched Google Books for [his hobby is boxing.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22his+hobby+is+boxing%22) Of the first 4 results, two are obviously people who box, and one is obviously only interested in getting a front-row seat to watch the action. The other one is an irrelevant oddball example: *His hobby is boxing, and he has boxed over 3400 items of various sizes, which he keeps in the trunk of his car.*

Answer (score 0):

They look good.

If you say: **My favourite hobby is *playing* football**.then you are being more specific (exact). You probably just enjoy **playing** football, but may or may not like watching or coaching it.

Both sentences might be understood to mean the same thing in the real world but as already stated it depends on the context of your conversation.